# CSS border not applying to table

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Changes to my table info on my CSS sheet doesn't seem to be changing when I run run the application.  The CSS is mostly pre-generated from when I created the MVC.  I just want tables to have borders so I added the "border: solid 2px black" portion.  However it doesn't seem to be adding the border. What am I doing wrong here? CSS:

```css
table {
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

th {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0;
}

th a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

th a:link,
th a:visited,
th a:active,
th a:hover {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
}

th a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

th.asc a,
th.desc a {
  margin-right: .75em;
}

th.asc a:after,
th.desc a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0em;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

th.asc a:after {
  content: '▲';
}

th.desc a:after {
  content: '▼';
}

td {
  padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
  border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
  padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Project ID
    </th>
    <th>
      Test1
    </th>
    <th>
      Test2
    </th>
    <th>
      Test3
    </th>
    <th>
      Test4
    </th>
    <th>
      Test5
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: id didn't show border around the whole table or you want border for cells too?

Comment: Run the snippet I have added to your question. The table has a border. Is this not what you are asking for?

Comment: use  border: solid 2px black !important;. some time your css class overwrite in other css class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and it's pretty stupid.  I needed to refresh the cache (Ctrl + F5).  It resulted in the changed CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and table has border!
Maybe there is another css code which Violates your style, so use !important

```css
border: solid 2px black !important;
```

---

if you want to border every cell use this code

```
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;}
```